# In Maven, can I pack JEE project in Zip archive together SQL scripts?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ear, rar

Hello everyone first of all,

Suppose I have a JEE project contents some modules and a 'sql' folder inside:

[image: The project structure image]

I build all modules to a 'integration-version.ear' archive file.
There is the content of my target:

[image: The content of target folder]

Using Maven, can I build something like this:

[image: The purposed content of target]

[image: The purposed structure of archive]

There is the ‘3.15’ folder includes some SQL files from the same folder of my project.

Is it possible? What is configuration of Maven needed?

---

**Note:**

The original question was like: "In Maven, can I pack JEE project in RAR archive together SQL scripts?" but now the question is changed because RAR is a proprietary format and each tools that create RAR files must be commercially licensed.

---

**Solution:**

Using *build-helper-maven-plugin*

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>parse-version</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <propertyPrefix>parsedVersion</propertyPrefix>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
...
```

Using *maven-assembly-plugin*

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/../assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
...
```

assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
   <id>release</id>
   <baseDirectory>${file.separator}</baseDirectory>
   <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
   </formats>
   <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
         <directory>${project.basedir}/../sql/migrates/${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}</directory>
         <outputDirectory>/scripts-${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}</outputDirectory>
         <includes>
            <include>**/*.sql</include>
         </includes>
      </fileSet>
   </fileSets>
   <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>       
        <outputFileNameMapping>${build.finalName}.${packaging}</outputFileNameMappin>
        <includes>
         <include>*:ear</include>
        </includes>
      </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Maven plugins which can do that: [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and [maven-rar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/)

If you want to use maven-rar-plugin, i would create a new module with packaging rar and configure the plugin.

I personally think maven-assembly-plugin is easier to use.

Comment: The `maven-rar-plugin` does not do what you think it does. In Java EE a `RAR` file is a way of packaging JCA implementations. It is **not** a compression format. i.e. The `maven-rar-plugin` creates a Java EE product, it is not for assembling an arbitrary collection of artifacts into a single file that has been compressed using the RAR format.

Comment: i think i missunderstood the question. What @JAlexey wanted is a rar archive (mime type application/x-rar-compressed)? i just tried to create the archives with maven-assembly-plugin and maven-rar-plugin, both are mime type application/zip. should i delete my answer?

Comment: I don't believe that the assembly plugin supports RAR archives, probably because it is a proprietary format. Tools that create RAR files must be commercially licensed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_(file_format). A good answer could explain this and then demonstrate how to use the assembly plugin to create a ZIP file. This might satisfy @JAlexey's requirement to package his EAR file and update scripts together.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answers. 
Now I understand that my question was incorrect. I hadn't thought about a format of archive.
I will change my question and add a note about the old version and that we had found out thanks to Steve C.
Zip is more suitable format for this purpose. I also use maven-assembly-plugin and tried maven-rar-plugin but I was not able to put my 'ear' file inside an archive. @Wirnse, if you are able to provide a simple example with settings it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Great that the missunderstanding is now cleared :-D. What you need is a `dependencySet` to add the `ear`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html).

Comment: Thank you, @Wirnse. I successfully configurated the plugin. The dependencySet fits for it very well. I will add a decription of my settings a little later.